# micronaut error reading application yml file

Tags: yaml, micronaut

We have updated micronaut from version 3.8.7 to 4.1.1.

We have included this conf in the application yml:

```
inbound:
  validations:
    FIELD_ONE:
      description: Check bla bla bla
      type: BASIC
    FIELD_TWO:
      description: Check bla bla bla
      type: BASIC
    FIELD_THREE:
      description: Check bla bla bla
      type: BASIC
```

also we have a class to load this configuration:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@EachProperty("inbound.validations")
public class ConfigBusinessValidator {
  public ConfigBusinessValidator(@Parameter String id) {
    this.validationId =
        BusinessValidatorEnum.customValueOf(id);
  }

  private Parameter validationId;
  private String description;
  private BusinessValidator.TYPE type = BusinessValidator.TYPE.NEED_DB_DATA;

}
```

With the previous micronaut version it worked correctly but with the 4.1.1 version the "@Parameter String id" is receiving the data modified:

For example:

- expected:  FIELD_ONE
- received: field-one

is there any default configuration that we have to change?